# Windows Form threading error

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, visual-studio

I have an error on a WinFrm app using threading. This code runs fine:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool keepGoing = true;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> 
        {
            while (keepGoing)
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(500);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Note the bool keepGoing variable within the event handler. If I put the bool keepGoing outside the event Handler and put a breakpoint within the loop  Visual Studio will stop working.

```
    bool keepGoing = true;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> 
        {
            while (keepGoing)
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(500);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the complete code using Win 10 and VS2015 and  .net 4.52.Both examples run it is only when you set a breakpoint on the second example within the while loop  that VS stops working. Why is this happening? I am trying to achieve both code versions to run exactly the same way - there is a problem with the second version on my machine but I don't know what it could be.

Comment: What do you mean by hangs? I have tried both examples and in both cases while loop "keep going".

Comment: Same... can't reproduce any hangs.

Comment: Same. I have the same structure in my code.

Comment: We have another option - to cancel task use Task.Factory.StartNew with cancelation token

Comment: If I place a breakpoint  before the while loop you cant step thru any further and the UI appears locked up for about 10 secs.The application will not continue.Using Win10 and VS 2015.

Comment: Nope.. Is you provide complete example?

Comment: @TheJack, what are you trying to achieve? Because I'm 99% sure that isn't the proper way to do it.

Comment: captured-variable(closure) problem is system and .Net version depended, probably it's the key

Answer (score 0):

Try to test this way:

```
    bool keepGoing = true;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Task.Factory.StartNew(Work);
    }

    private void Work()
    {
        while (keepGoing)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```